# How to access a Bash variable from another function?

Tags: bash, function, global-variables

I have a Bash function that contains a variable that I need to access from another function. How do I do this?

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash 

function run_query() {
    sleep 5
    local -g DATA=$(curl "http://api.dictionary.words/?definition=program")
}

function display_data() {
    printf "%s\n" "$DATA"
}

run_query &
display_data
```

Comment: Try doing `declare -g` instead of `local -g`. The documentation for `local` does say that it accepts any option that is valid for `declare`, but `local -g` is an oxymoron, and I doubt the shell respects the `-g` flag in that context. Even if it does, it's unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: Also, by running `run_query` in the background (by appending the `&`), it is effectively running in a subshell and therefore cannot modify data from the parent shell (i.e., the shell your script is running in).

Comment: Thanks. The first function runs every 5 seconds and the second function runs every second because I did not want to query the API every second. So since the variable $DATA runs in a subshell I will not be able to access it....

Comment: You can always redirect the data to a file and then just `cat` the file once per second in your script.

Comment: You are right about the redirection. Great idea!

Comment: Is there a way to redirect the output to memory instead of creating a file on the disk? That way I would not have to write to disk every five seconds.

Comment: bash is not really the right thing to write multi-threaded programs in. I'd recommend either using another language, or rethinking it to be single-threaded. How about just using a single loop that queries the API on every fifth iteration?

Comment: You can write to a tmpfs instead of the disk

Comment: When you display `$DATA` every second, do you want to print the same unchanged data 5 times in a row? Perhaps you want a named pipe, catching all new data that is read from `run_query()` each second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first function runs every 5 seconds and the second function runs
>   every second because I did not want to query the API every second.

Then, you can query every 5 seconds

```
i=0
while :
do
    ((i++ % 5 == 0)) && data=$(curl "http://api.dictionary.words/?definition=program")
    printf '%s\n' "$data"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you are running run_query as a background process, in a subshell with &.
Thus, run_query and display data are not being ran in the same shell so they cannot access each others variables.

Just something to try,

Call display_data from within run_query()

```
function display_data() {
    printf("%s\n" "$1")
}
export -f display_data 
function run_query() {
    sleep 5
    DATA="$(curl "some_url" --someoptions)"
    display_data "$DATA"
}
export -f run_query
```